# MyBatis Migrations - how to apply missing migration

Tags: git, mybatis

Quite often it happens that some developer sends to git migration with delay (which was created before last migrations at given machine), in such case penultimate migration remains not applied, is there any way to force performing this one missing migration ?

Currently we're just applying it manually.

Comment: Actually git in this question is a synonym for any VCS :) the problem is not connected with any of them, just pure MyBatis

Comment: There is a 'pending' command. Please see the [doc](https://mybatis.org/migrations/pending.html).

Answer (score 0):

I've also encoutered this problem. My solution to this is not perfect, but it's simple and at least one does not have to do manual sql queries. :-)

Mybatis handles migrations according to the "timestamp" string in the beginning of migration file name. It doesn't apply new migrations if they have older timestamp than the most recent migration applied. So, if some migration file does not get applied, just change the timestamp of that migration to e.g. current time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Pending instead Up in MyBatis. This operation allows to ignore order. Documentation: https://mybatis.org/migrations/pending.html

Code example:

```
      try {
            new PendingOperation().operate(new DataSourceConnectionProvider(createDataSource()),
                new FileMigrationLoader(getScriptDir(), "utf-8", getProperties()), getOption(), System.out);
        } catch (MigrationException e) {
            System.out.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
```